# Inject a Java object in a JSF Named bean

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, java-ee-6, cdi

I have a JSF2 bean used as a controller for my view:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class PosController implements Serializable {

  @EJB FatturaFacade fatturaFacade;

  // ...
}
```

As you can see I already can inject one of my EJBs (used as a dao wrapper) inside it, but what's the way for injecting a "simple" object? And what if I have different implementations as follows?

```
interface Retriever;
class WebServiceRetriever implements Retriever;
class FileRetriever implements Retriever;
```

I saw the `@interface` annotation, but I didn't understand it well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a full Java EE 6 platform the best approach is to use CDI's `@Inject`.

The simplest mechanism would be to use the concrete types:

```
public class Bean {
  @Inject
  private WebServiceRetriever webServiceRetriever;

  @Inject
  private FilesRetriever filesRetriever;

  //etc.
```

For multiple implementations of the same interface you can create [@Qualifier](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Qualifier.html) annotations. Their usage is explained in the [Using Qualifiers section of the Java EE 6 tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbck.html).

A `@Files` qualifier:

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({TYPE, METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER})
public @interface Files {}
```

The `FileRetriever` implementation:

```
@Files
public class FileRetriever implements Retriever {}
```

Disambiguation of the `Retriever` implementations in the injection target:

```
public class Bean {
  @Inject @WebServices
  private Retriever webServiceRetriever;

  @Inject @Files
  private Retriever filesRetriever;

  //etc.
```

There is a post on my blog on [using JSF with CDI](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/jsf-cdi-and-el.html) that you might find useful.